# cat doesn't join my files when I run inside script

Tags: shell, ubuntu, scripting

I'm doing a restore backups script, and when I try to join files which are splitted, cat prints that error:

```
cat: fullbackup_mrbsNuevo_15_6_2016.tar.gz.*: No such file or directory
```

The line that runs cat command is this one:

```
cat $type"_"$NAME_DIR"_"$d"_"$2"_"$1".tar.gz."\* > $type"_"$NAME_DIR"_"$d"_"$2"_"$1".tar.gz"
```

I have checked if the files exist and they are in the directory. Also I have tried running the command in the shell and works fine.

I don't know what is bad in my script.

When I run the ls command in the directory the files are:

```
cisco@Paquito1:/tmp/backup$ ls -lah
total 7,1M
drwxr-xr-x 2 cisco cisco 4,0K 2016-06-18 12:01 .
drwxrwxrwt 5 root  root  4,0K 2016-06-18 10:10 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 cisco cisco 5,0M 2016-06-18 11:52 fullbackup_mrbsNuevo_15_6_2016.tar.gz.aa
-rw-r--r-- 1 cisco cisco 2,1M 2016-06-18 11:52 fullbackup_mrbsNuevo_15_6_2016.tar.gz.ab
```

And before executing the cat command I move to the /tmp/backup directory.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure the file ends with a literal star? The star is escaped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you shouldn't escape `*`, this will result in shell/bash searching for a litteral star, not expanding filename.

try

```
cat $type"_"$NAME_DIR"_"$d"_"$2"_"$1".tar.gz."* > $type"_"$NAME_DIR"_"$d"_"$2"_"$1".tar.gz"
```

edit

on a side note I would quote

```
cat ${type}_${NAME_DIR}_${d}_${2}_${1}.tar.gz.* > ${type}_${NAME_DIR}_${d}_${2}_${1}.tar.gz"
```

Comment: Without escaping the * in the script, neither works.
ls -lah fullbackup_mrbsNuevo_15_6_2016.tar.gz.\* says me that:
cisco@Paquito1:/tmp/backup$ ls -lah fullbackup_mrbsNuevo_15_6_2016.tar.gz.\*
ls: cannot access fullbackup_mrbsNuevo_15_6_2016.tar.gz.*: No such file or directory

Comment: If in the ls command I don't escape the * show me the files.

Answer (score 0):

Finally this was the solution:

```
cat $type"_"$NAME_DIR"_"$d"_"$2"_"$1".tar.gz."* > $type"_"$NAME_DIR"_"$d"_"$2"_"$1".tar.gz"
```

I haven't escaped the * and I put it outside of "". Thanks to Archemar for his answer. He helps me to find my error.

Comment: you don't need to enter and exit the double quotes so many times.  try this instead, it's easier to read and easier to edit.  `cat "$type_$NAME_DIR_$d_$2_$1.tar.gz."* > "$type_$NAME_DIR_$d_$2_$1.tar.gz"`.  Or, using bash a array, `tarfiles=( $type_$NAME_DIR_$d_$2_$1.tar.gz.* ); cat "${tarfiles[@]}" > "$type_$NAME_DIR_$d_$2_$1.tar.gz"`. BTW, if you're redirecting the output to a .tar.gz file to unsplit it before un-taring it, you don't need to.  you can pipe the output of the `cat` directly into `tar xf -`

Comment: Thanks for your advices, I'm not an expert in shell scripts.